# python 2.7, вывод в той же строке

Tags: python, python-2.x

Добрый вечер.

Как известно print в языке python начинает выводить на следующую строку.
Как мне напечатать в той же строке?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print 'hello ',
print 'world'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('text', end='')
```

[Документация](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)